# Entity Framework GroupBy, Select all if one

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GSDQ.png) and I want to Group the table by its Id, and also for example, if I search for "Statoil Nig Ltd" in `ValStr` column, I want to retrieve all the data in `ValStr` with the same id (323439, in such a way that each can be used individually like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xNlG.png) (i.e title will be a string from the `ValStr`, address will be another string).

So far this is what I've done:

```
var groups = _entities.LLAttrDatas
    .Where(r => r.ValStr.Contains("4502207741") && r.AttrID == 2)
    .GroupBy(r => r.ID);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List with ID == {0}", group.Key);

    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        if (item.ValStr.Contains("4502207741") && item.AttrID == 2)
        {
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" Item: {0}", item.ValStr);
    }
}
```

Please how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're looking for...
If you want to get all sets, grouped by ID, that share a common value (valStr /w given AttrId) then what you have is close to there:

```
var ids = _entities.LLAttrDatas
  .Where(r=> r.Valstr.Contains("4502207741") && r.AttrId == 2)
  .Select(r=> r.ID);
var groups = _entities.LLAtrDatas
  .Where(r=> ids.Contains(r.ID))
  .GroupBy(r=> r.ID);
```

From there you would have a set of Groups of related items, by ID, that each contained the requested search criteria.

Comment: Please how do i display each group result individually...by the Valstr and AttrId?

Comment: The code you had should do so, foreach(var group in groups) /w the foreach(var item in groups) would give you access to an LLAttrData entity. To find a particular valstr and attr in a group: var data = group.SingleOrDefault(r=>r.AttrId == 4);  would give you the item in the current grouped set where the AttrId was 4. (Assuming one AttrId value per each ID)

Comment: Thank you so much...Really appreciate